# How to print zeros and ones of a file

Tags: terminal, hardware, binary, xxd

*Long story short:* how to print in a terminal the binary digits constituting a file e.g. a library *.so* or a simple text *.txt* file

---

*PC hardware works with electrical signal (basically it's an ON/OFF behaviour) which is well logically translated by the binary system (digits 0s and 1s). Visualizing the content of a file would be an interesting **educational exercise**, as well as comparing a .txt and an executable that prints the same text.*

Comment: Please provide sample input and output

Comment: You should explain the exact purpose of such output. Tody very few people can make sense of binary numbers; instead they use tools like `objdump`, `hexdump` or disassemblers.

Comment: If you want to do a lot of visualization of binary numbers it would be useful for you to learn how and why hex numbers are used.

Answer (score 19):

`xxd` can give binary output.  Example below.

```
$ cat foo
Hello World
$ xxd -b foo
00000000: 01001000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111 00100000  Hello
00000006: 01010111 01101111 01110010 01101100 01100100 00001010  World.
$
```

Comment: Thanks! for sake of completeness it is included in the `vim` or `gvim` package on Arch Linux

Comment: BTW, that `.` at the end (00001010) is an ASCII newline `NL`. Since its first 4 bits are all zero, it's an unprintable ASCII control character so xxd just prints `.`

Comment: Is this ASCII bits or UTF8 bits?

Comment: The example file `foo` is ASCII encoded.

Comment: @JeremyBoden the right side is ASCII. A byte is 8 bits: `00000000`. ASCII maps 7 bit numbers to characters `00000000` - `01111111`. The first bit isn't used by ASCII, it's always `0`. UTF-8 is a system that extends ASCII, essentially it says "if the first bit is `0`, read the byte as ASCII, if the first bit is `1` read the next 1, 2 or 3 bytes as well and use [this scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Encoding) to interpret that set of bytes as a number which is then mapped to a character". So it's ASCII, characters outside of ASCII will be displayed as `..` `...` or `....`.

Answer (score 13):

With `basenc` (from [coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/basenc-invocation.html))

```
$ echo 123 | basenc --base2msbf -w8
00110001
00110010
00110011
00001010
```